# MSFC “the Cluster name is not online”

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, failovercluster

i have a microsoft 2008 failovercluster in my lab with, also, an unproductive dns server. Unfortunately i had a hdd-crash and recover my cluster from backup.

But now, in cluster manager i see always the message the cluster name is not online.

In the eventviewer i have five entries with error od 1207. i try everything and grant the permissons. but it doesn't solve the issue afer a lot of reboots.

So, is there a way to repair the dns entries or delete the dns entries and the cluster can create the entries from scratch?

Thank you for reading this

BR Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cluster stay offline after restore the nodes from backup and put them again into the domain. Sorry, i forgot this in my question.

I read a lot of threads and Posts from microsoft. But nothing helps.

One thrad looks promises and solved my problem finally.

[Here is the solution](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csstwplatform/archive/2010/10/15/cluster-network-name-resource-cluster-name-cannot-be-brought-online-unable-to-get-computer-object-using-guid.aspx)

BR Frank